# Is getting mile markers in Apple MapKit or Google Maps SDK possible?

Tags: ios, maps, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I can't find any documentation about using mile markers, only latitude and longitude. Is this even possible? Basically the situation is I get a JSON with a road and a mile marker and I want to be able to represent that data on a map.  I know I could tediously convert mile markers to coordinates, but that just seems asinine. Is there another way?

Comment: You'll need to explain what mile-markers are before anyone can tell you if they can be used. An example of the JSON you receive would be a good start.

Comment: @Craig, perhaps it's because you don't live in the US.  Mile-markers are a little sign on every highway and interstate indicating where you are. It is basically a number from 0 to the end of the road,  however many miles that would be. So the beginning of the road would be 0 and every mile along the road there will be a another sign with the next number or you are driving the opposite direction they would start at the higher number and go down. They also coincide with the exit numbers on the interstates.

Comment: Yes, we have those too thanks. But are you getting IDs of the mile markers and then expecting there to be a database of all mile marker locations or are you getting the number 0, 1, 2, 3 and then expecting to be able to calculate the position of the road just by knowing that some part of the road is 5 miles from the start of the road?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need outside data for this. Check state or even US DOT data sources for something you could use here. You could then represent it on a map with MapKit directly (annotations) or possibly look into making your own raster layer with [Mapbox Studio](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-studio).